# Separar y mostrar productos de un JSON por categoría con jQuery,

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Necesito listar los productos separador por categorías. Tengo un *script* REST que actualmente me lista dichos productos todos a la vez, pero necesito mostrarlos tal como se ve en la captura de pantalla adjunta. Los recupero en formato JSON, la FK que determina la categoría es "tipo"(string) y la id es "id_producto".
No sé cómo manejar el `each` para este cometido.

[image: captura json]

El código es este

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  app.readPosts();
  $(document).bind('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady); 
});
 var app = {
  posts_url: "http://www.web.com/json/lista.json.php",
  onDeviceReady: function() {
    console.log('Device is ready');
    app.readPosts();    
  },
  readPosts: function() {
    console.log('Reading posts');
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: app.posts_url,
      success: app.onSuccess,
      error: app.onError
    });
    console.log('Reading posts asynchrounously');
  },
  onSuccess: function(data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
      items.push('<div id="card-525495'+val.id_producto+'"><div class="card"><div class="card-header graph"><div class="row"><div class="col-8"><a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#card-525495'+val.id_producto+'" href="#card-element-557833'+val.id_producto+'"><div class="diplinline">'+val.tipo+' - '+val.nombre+'</div></a></div><div class="col-4"><div class="row"><div class="col-8"><div class="diplinline text-right">'+val.precio+'&euro;</div></div><div class="col-4"><div class="upper" id="'+val.id_producto+'"><h5><span class="badge badge-success">+</span></h5><span class="name" style="display:none">'+val.nombre+'</span>><span class="price"  style="display:none">'+val.precio+'</span></div></div></div></div></div></div><div id="card-element-557833'+val.id_producto+'" class="collapse"><div class="card-body"><h4>'+val.tipo+' - '+val.nombre+'</h4><p>'+val.ingredientes+'</p><img src="img/'+val.imagen+'" class="items" height="100" alt="" />'+val.precio+'<p>'+val.ingredientes+'</p></div></div></div></div>'); 
    });
$('#posts').html(items.join(''));
}
},
onError: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log('Data: ' + data);
  console.log('Status: ' + textStatus);
  console.log('Error: ' + errorThrown);
  $("#posts").html('No hay tareas pendientes');
  console.log('Exiting onError');
},
```

};

y la salida la muestro con esto:

```
<div data-role="content" id="posts"></div>
```

este es el JSON resultante.

```
[{"id_producto":"1","nombre":"Cool T-shirt","imagen":"tshirt-1.jpg","ingredientes":"Cool T-shirt, Cotton Fabric. Wash in normal water with mild detergent.","precio":"8.50","tipo":"pizzas"},{"id_producto":"2","nombre":"HBD T-Shirt","imagen":"tshirt-2.jpg","ingredientes":"Cool Happy Birthday printed T-shirt.Crafted from light, breathable cotton.","precio":"7.40","tipo":"pizzas"},{"id_producto":"3","nombre":"Survival of Fittest","imagen":"tshirt-3.jpg","ingredientes":"Yellow t-shirt makes the perfect addition to your casual wardrobe.","precio":"9.50","tipo":"pizzas"},{"id_producto":"4","nombre":"Love Hate T-shirt","imagen":"tshirt-4.jpg","ingredientes":"Stylish and trendy, this crew neck short sleeved t-shirt is made with 100% pure cotton.","precio":"10.80","tipo":"bocadillos"}]
```

Comment: Disculpa, ¿no podrías agregar un ejemplo del json que obtienes con ajax?

Comment: @the-breaker cómo no. Lo pongo. Gracias por el apunte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer cambiando el código en `onSuccess`:

Se crear 3 variables, una para guardar el HTML final que se insertará, una para guardar las categorías y la ultima para guardar el HTML generado para cada elemento del json según su categoría.

```
var contenido='<ul>';
var items = {};
var cats = [];
```

Luego al recorrer el json verificas que si el tipo del elemento aun no esta en el array de categorías:

```
if(!cats.includes(val.tipo)){
```

De ser así lo insertas e inicializas la lista de items de la categoría:

```
cats.push(val.tipo);
items[val.tipo]='';
```

Agregas el item a la lista con:

```
items[val.tipo]+=`<li>${val.nombre}</li>`;
```

Por ultimo recorres el *array* de categorías añadiendo el contenido de cada lista para mostrarlo:

```
cats.map(e => contenido+=`<li>${e.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+e.substr(1)}</li><ul>${items[e]}</ul>`)
$('#posts').html(contenido+'</ul>');
```

Este código añade letra capital al nombre de la categoría.
En lugar de usar `<ul>` y `<li>` puedes emplear otras etiquetas para mostrar los elementos.

Este es un ejemplo de como funcionaria:

```js
var data=JSON.parse('[{"id_producto":"1","nombre":"Cool T-shirt","imagen":"tshirt-1.jpg","ingredientes":"Cool T-shirt, Cotton Fabric. Wash in normal water with mild detergent.","precio":"8.50","tipo":"pizzas"},{"id_producto":"2","nombre":"HBD T-Shirt","imagen":"tshirt-2.jpg","ingredientes":"Cool Happy Birthday printed T-shirt.Crafted from light, breathable cotton.","precio":"7.40","tipo":"pizzas"},{"id_producto":"3","nombre":"Survival of Fittest","imagen":"tshirt-3.jpg","ingredientes":"Yellow t-shirt makes the perfect addition to your casual wardrobe.","precio":"9.50","tipo":"pizzas"},{"id_producto":"4","nombre":"Love Hate T-shirt","imagen":"tshirt-4.jpg","ingredientes":"Stylish and trendy, this crew neck short sleeved t-shirt is made with 100% pure cotton.","precio":"10.80","tipo":"bocadillos"}]');

function mostrar() {
    var contenido='<ul>';
    var items = {};
    var cats = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
      if(!cats.includes(val.tipo)){
        cats.push(val.tipo);
        items[val.tipo]='';
      }
      items[val.tipo]+=`<li>${val.nombre}</li>`;   
    });
    cats.map(e => contenido+=`<li>${e.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+e.substr(1)}</li><ul>${items[e]}</ul>`)
    $('#posts').html(contenido+'</ul>');
}

mostrar();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="content" id="posts"></div>
```

y el código al final te queda de esta forma:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  app.readPosts();
  $(document).bind('deviceready', app.onDeviceReady); 
});
var app = {
  posts_url: "http://www.web.com/json/lista.json.php",
  onDeviceReady: function() {
    console.log('Device is ready');
    app.readPosts();        
  },
  readPosts: function() {
    console.log('Reading posts');
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: app.posts_url,
      success: app.onSuccess,
      error: app.onError
    });
    console.log('Reading posts asynchrounously');
  },
  onSuccess: function(data) {
    var items = [];
    var contenido='<ul>';
    var items = {};
    var cats = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, val){
      if(!cats.includes(val.tipo)){
        cats.push(val.tipo);
        items[val.tipo]='';
      }
      items[val.tipo]+=`<li>${val.nombre}</li>`;   
    });
    cats.map(e => contenido+=`<li>${e.substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+e.substr(1)}</li><ul>${items[e]}</ul>`)
    $('#posts').html(contenido+'</ul>');
  }
},
  onError: function(data, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('Data: ' + data);
    console.log('Status: ' + textStatus);
    console.log('Error: ' + errorThrown);
    $("#posts").html('No hay tareas pendientes');
    console.log('Exiting onError');
  },
};
```

y así ya se muestra como esperas, saludos.

Comment: brillante. Y además sencillo y lógico. Thanks!

Comment: @rafa_pe de nada, para eso estamos.